# How to save "window history state" in the current path?

Tags: angular

I need to save "window history state" in the current path, for example {offset: 10}.
Then I can go to another path, and after I go back (location.back()), I get to the previous path with the saved state ({offset: 10})
How can I save the state?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for push state `(history.pushState(state, title, [,url]))`.
He's an example:

```
history.pushState(null, null, "my-page.html?offset=10";
```

Ref = https://www.javascripttutorial.net/web-apis/javascript-history-pushstate/